# Fixing image not showing Laravel with data-bg-img

Tags: css, laravel, image

I need to add an image to my laravel blade using data-bg-img

I am new to larvel currently using Laravel 5.8, I have the regular routing, my image is in the image/bg folder which is in the public folder

```
<section class="inner-header divider parallax layer-overlay overlay-dark-6" data-bg-img="{{asset('/images/bg/bg6.jpg') }}">
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please read about [How to Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in this site. Always be specific and make your best effort before asking. In this case, you show us a line of code that might have 1000 possibilities to fail. I recommend you to add your directory tree, the HTML response in the browser or any error that you identified. Then we can try to fix it or give you an advice.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use style then data-bg  to make the image appear as a proper CSS background-image, like this:

style="background-image: url(images/bg/bg6.jpg")"

So you code:

```
<section class="inner-header divider parallax layer-overlay overlay-dark-6" style="background-image: url(images/bg/bg6.jpg")">
```

Hope it helps :D

Comment: Great, glad I can help, if you can just upvote the answer :D thx